# Log4j to json event for logstash

Tags: log4j, logstash, pingfederate

So I'm trying to get some usable format from Pingfederate's server.log files to be able to send over to logstash. Instead of screwing around with alot of grok pattern filters, I found log4j-jsonevent-layout (https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout) and decided to give it a try. Unfortunately, it appears that my server.log file is no longer being updated at all. Just wondering if anyone has had experience with this logstash plugin before.

Here is my section of log4j.xml

```
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.home.dir}/log/server.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="true"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
     <layout class="net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1"/>
   </appender>
```

The only thing I have changed about this part is the layout class. Which is correctly loaded into the classpath for pingfederate.

Using log4j version 1.26.2.1

Comment: What version of PF is this? Are you intentionally logging to the JBOSS home directory and not "${pf.log.dir}/server.log"/>"?

Comment: Sorry this log4j.xml came from PF 6.3 I believe. We had done a migration to 7 and that's the reason it was referencing the old way.

Comment: I'd correct the variable as a first step and give it another try if you haven't already.